Group bucket value per label in the Prometheus' histogram data for Grafana dashboard
I have a Prometheus datasource configured in Grafana dashboard.
I need to show metric for response latency.
The visual componenet of choice (so far) is Bar Gauge.
Now, I have data which are basically from two sources under one metric distinguished by 'label' (endpoint).
so it comes in something like this:
_server_request_response_latency_histogram{endpoint="http://192.168.0.1:6090/",le="0.75",} 1.0
        _server_request_response_latency_histogram{endpoint="http://192.168.0.1:6090/",le="1.0",} 1.0
        _server_request_response_latency_histogram{endpoint="http://192.168.0.1:6090/",le="7.5",} 1.0
        _server_request_response_latency_histogram{endpoint="http://192.168.0.1:6090/",le="10.0",} 6.0
        _server_request_response_latency_histogram{endpoint="http://192.168.0.1:6090/",le="+Inf",} 696.0
        _server_request_response_latency_histogram{endpoint="http://192.168.0.2:6090/",le="0.005",} 0.0
        _server_request_response_latency_histogram{endpoint="http://192.168.0.2:6090/",le="0.01",} 0.0
        _server_request_response_latency_histogram{endpoint="http://192.168.0.2:6090/",le="0.025",} 0.0
        _server_request_response_latency_histogram{endpoint="http://192.168.0.2:6090/",le="0.05",} 0.0
        _server_request_response_latency_histogram{endpoint="http://192.168.0.2:6090/",le="+Inf",} 696.0

on the dashboard I need to be able to distinguish between labels sent (now two), so I would need some king of grouping per bucket or so. Now it looks like this:

which is not well readable.
Can you recommend a proper way of displaying this metric, please?
I am new to grafana so I would appreciate an example too, please.
Thanks!
Grafana v. 10.x
EDIT: would be great to end up with something to this effect:

just a multiple histograms in one grouped by label
Thanks!
